# Passing object instance in nodejs via require

Tags: node.js, mongodb, requirejs

I am new to node and struggle  hard to achieve an objective where i can return an object instance to the caller method.

Please note : object instance is getting created in a non blocking callback, and I want to pass this object back to the main module from where this has been invoked, I am able to achieve this in the same file (file b.js) but not in the main file (file a.js) using require.

example code in file b.js

```
var object1 = require('object1.js')
  function createobject(){
     object1.someFunction(err,function(myobj){
        //retrun myobj to the caller function; 
         return myobj;
    });
   }
module.exports = createobject;
```

In a.js

```
var b = require('b.js');
var myobj = b.createObject(); 
//call some method of myobj
```

Please suggest experts, 
Thanks,
Manish Bansal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typical problem to someone new. You're trying to return something from `async` function - which doesn't work. Use callback or promises instead:

`file b.js`

```
function createobject(next){
   object1.someFunction(err,function(myobj){
      //retrun myobj to the caller function; 
       next(myobj);
  });
}
```

`file a.js`

```
b.createObject(function (myobj) {
  // call some method of myobj
});
```

Comment: +1 thanks, this was very quick, so just wanted to confirm is there any other way over this, or this is the only option returning something from async.. nevertheless much appreciated :)

Comment: Yes, this is the only way. Unless you use [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) or [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)